# Keydown event throwing TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I'm trying to implement a keyboard event to detect if the user has the Caps Lock on is on while typing in an input field, so I have my component like this:

```
<span onkeyup="{!c.keyCheck}">
    <lightning:input aura:id="pwInput" type="password" label="Password" />
</span>
```

I'm using the [`event.getModifierState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/getModifierState) method to pass the "CapsLock" key value:

```
keyCheck : function(component, event, helper) {       
    if (event.getModifierState("CapsLock")) {
        console.log("Caps lock on");
    } else {
        console.log("Caps lock off");
    }
}
```

This is throwing a `TypeError: Illegal invocation` error:

```
TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at Object.l (aura_prod.js:24)
    at Object.checkCapsLock (MyComponent.js:258)
    at keyCheck (MyComponent.js:78)
    at J.Uc (aura_prod.js:507)
    at aura_prod.js:399
    at $.B.gb (aura_prod.js:834)
    at Object.Vi (aura_prod.js:399)
    at Object.gp (aura_prod.js:399)
    at HTMLSpanElement.b (aura_prod.js:830)
    at HTMLSpanElement.t.$$lwcEventWrapper$$ (aura_prod.js:2)
```

I can do this on a [plain HTML page](https://codepen.io/AllThingsSmitty/pen/XBLEPM) so I don't know why I'm getting this  error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Might have something to do with locker service.

Comment: `console.log(event);` shows `getModifierState: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
    at Function.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:2:14)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like locker service does not like `getModifierState`.

You have to implement `isCapsLock` in an old school way as present here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348792/how-do-you-tell-if-caps-lock-is-on-using-javascript).

Get `KeyCode` of the character, check if its A to Z and if Shift is pressed or not to determine if caps's lock is turned on or not.

I quickly tested this out and it works like a charm.

Controler:

```
({
    keyCheck : function(component, event, helper) {  
        console.log(helper.isCapslock(event));

    }

})
```

Helper:

```
({
    isCapslock :function(e){

        e = (e) ? e : window.event;

        var charCode = false;
        if (e.which) {
            charCode = e.which;
        } else if (e.keyCode) {
            charCode = e.keyCode;
        }

        var shifton = false;
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            shifton = e.shiftKey;
        } else if (e.modifiers) {
            shifton = !!(e.modifiers & 4);
        }
        if (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122 && shifton) {
            return true;
        }

        if (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90 && !shifton) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

})
```

Comment: Thanks Pranay! `keyCode` [is deprecated no](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) so I was hoping to go with `getModiferState()`, but if Locker Service is restricting it then I may have no choice. Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: The only thing about this solution is that is only tells me if a user is typing either an alpha or non-alpha character, and only if the Caps Lock was pressed, but not the state of the Caps Lock (on/off), which what what `getModiferState()` does. Unfortunately I don't think this will work for me.